# Etiqueta puede contener atributo for

Tags: html, css

Tengo este código simple. Funciona a la perfección excepto en una cosa. Si yo pulso encima de *Configurar alto*, el checkbox se activa, puesto que dicha acción se realiza con un atributo for en la etiqueta `<p>`, pero si el mismo atributo lo aplico a la etiqueta `<span>`, como se puede ver en el ejemplo, y luego pulso encima del span, que es el cuadro gris, no se activa el checkbox, pero si que se sigue activando si pulso las palabras. ¿Por qué está ocurriendo esto y hay alguna solución?

```css
span {
    font-family:Helvetica;
    user-select: none;
    background-color: #ededed;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    margin-right: 8px;
    padding: 4px 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: -2px;
}
```

```html
<p><span for="myId"><input id="myId" type="checkbox"/><label for="myId"><b>Configurar alto</b></label></span></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si tu mismo revisas la [especificación](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/textlevel-semantics.html#the-span-element) notarás como un elemento `span` no posee significado semántico a menos que sea mezclado su uso con alguna de las etiquetas ahi mencionadas.

Por otro lado si nos referimos a la documentación de [Mozilla Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/span) observarás que los atributos de un `span` son:

- title
- id
- class
- style
- lang
- dir

y además:

- datasrc
- datafld
- dataformatas

Entonces de forma nativa comprobamos que no posee la funcionalidad que tu estás buscando.

Por otro lado una etiqueta `label` posee un atributo llamado `for` que sirve y cito<sup>1</sup>:

> El ID del elemento de formulario etiquetable relacionado en el mismo documento que el elemento label. El primer elemento en el documento con tal ID que coincida con el dispuesto en el atributo for será el control etiquetado para este elemento.

Por lo tanto si quieres vincular al `input` deberá ser con un `label`

**Referencia**

- [etiqueta label](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/label)<sup>1</sup>